# iOS | Alamofire, how to send raw JSON data to body

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, post, alamofire

I have a question about sending a raw JSON to an endpoint using Alamofire.

Using the code below

```
let request = AF.request("URL OF ENDPOINT", method: .post, parameters: ["FirstName" : "kwstas"], encoder: URLEncodedFormParameterEncoder(destination: .httpBody), headers: headers).responseJSON{ (response) in
                //Check the result from Alamofire's response and check if it's a success or a failure
                switch response.result {
                case .success(let value):
                    //Everything is fine, return the value in onNext
                    observer.onNext(value)
                    observer.onCompleted()
                case .failure(let error):
                    //Something went wrong, switch on the status code and return the error
                    switch response.response?.statusCode {
                    case 403:
                        observer.onError(ApiError.forbidden)
                    case 404:
                        observer.onError(ApiError.notFound)
                    case 409:
                        observer.onError(ApiError.conflict)
                    case 500:
                        observer.onError(ApiError.internalServerError)
                    default:
                        observer.onError(error)
                    }
                }
            }
```

At least i get a failure that the endpoint wants more values ( which it does)

But using anything else rather than encoder URLEncodedFormParameterEncoder(destination: .httpBody) (for example JSONEncoder.default) the request doesnt even return a response ( success or failure ).

The thing is that i have a dictionary that receives multiple values ( int, string , array of objects) and when i pass my dictionary (which is of type String : Any) to the parameters i get an error that Protocol 'Any' as a type cannot conform to 'Encodable'.

Any answers will be much appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you want something like this :

```
        var memberJson : String = ""
    do{
        let jsonEncoder = JSONEncoder()
        let jsonData = try jsonEncoder.encode(yourJson)
        memberJson = String(data: jsonData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)!
    
        
    }catch{}

    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "url here")
    request.httpMethod = HTTPMethod.post.rawValue
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.httpBody = (memberJson).data(using: .unicode)
    AF.request(request).responseJSON{response in }
```

Comment: Until now this works perfectly, i will test it a little bit more and i will accept your answer if it works as expected.

Comment: Tell me if its not working @Nion